# How convert it to Doctrine QueryBuilder?

Tags: sql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

How convert it to Doctrine QueryBuilder?

```
SELECT A.*
,(SELECT COUNT(created_on) 
    FROM event WHERE DATE=created_on) created
,(SELECT COUNT(updated_on)
    FROM event WHERE DATE=updated_on) updated
FROM (
SELECT created_on DATE FROM event
UNION SELECT updated_on FROM event ) A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) does not support subqueries in the `SELECT` clause, nor the `UNION` clause. Please check [DQL's EBNF](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf) to see what the supported features are. Consider using [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) if your query needs this degree of complexity.